# How do I get the size of the entire usable screen in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm messing around with Kivy in Python 3 and while it gives me the option to get the size of the Kivy window, it won't give me any way to get the size of the entire usable screen of my current device.

If it can't be done within Kivy, I at least need something totally cross-platform because that's the entire point of why I'm using Kivy.

Answer (score 1):

There was recently a [pull request](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4286#issuecomment-228581172) exactly about that thing, yet it wasn't merged. For some reason I don't see it in Plyer too, so probably it was dropped or something. Which means:

1. `git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy`
2. patch the `_window_sdl2.pyx` and `window_sdl2.py` files
3. (re)compile

and you should be good to go with getting the screen size via `Window.get_currentdisplaymode()`.

It won't work if you use wheels or any other form of already compiled package of Kivy, where the Cython files are missing (no source to recompile from).

Comment: is this in master now? Looks like its not.:( Still no good answer to this question...?